# Read chunks of data in Perl

Tags: perl

What is a good way in Perl to split a line into pieces of varying length, when there is no delimiter I can use. My data is organized by column length, so the first variable is in positions 1-4, the second variable is positions 5-15, etc. There are many variables each with different lengths.

Put another way, is there some way to use the split function based on the position in the string, not a matched expression?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes there is. The [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) function is well-suited to dealing with fixed-width records.

#### Example

```
my $record = "1234ABCDEFGHIJK";
my @fields = unpack 'A4A11', $record;  # 1st field is 4 chars long, 2nd is 11

print "@fields";                       # Prints '1234 ABCDEFGHIJK'
```

The first argument is the template, which tells `unpack` where the fields begin and end. The second argument tells it which string to unpack.

`unpack` can also be told to ignore character positions in a string by specifying null bytes, `x`. The template `'A4x2A9'` could be used to ignore the `"AB"` in the example above.

See [`perldoc -f pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [`perldoc perlpacktut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html) for in-depth details and examples.

Comment: I always like to include whitespace in the template string, ie unpack('A4 A11 A1 A4 A6', $record); It has no effect on its behaviour, but makes it a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `split`, try the old-school [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) method:

```
my $first = substr($input, 0, 4);
my $second = substr($input, 5, 10);
# etc...
```

(I like the unpack method too, but substr is easier to write without consulting the documentation, if you're only parsing out a few fields.)

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `substr()` function to extract data by offset:

```
$first = substr($line, 0, 4);
$second = substr($line, 4, 11);
```

Another option is to use a regular expression:

```
($first, $second) = ($line =~ /(.{4})(.{11})/);
```